# Spring WS request scope

Tags: java, spring, scope, request

Spring has request scope when processing HTTP/HTML requests. My application processes SOAP messages instead. Is there a way to have a request scope for Spring WS?

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @fateddy I need a scope for the SOAP message/request processing just like request scope for HTTP/HTML request/message processing.

Comment: What do you mean by `scope` (request scoped beans?). Could you add an example?

Comment: SOAP is generally over HTTP. So, should not it work fine with request scope? @Bolot

Answer (score 0):

SOAP may rely on many application layer protocols such as HTTP, SMTP, FTP, JMS.

About your implementation, if SOAP is over HTTP then you can use [RequestScope](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestScope.html)

Otherwise, you can check [SimpleThreadScope](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/SimpleThreadScope.html). This scope is not a default scope which means you should register it in application startup.